# R - Scatter plots, how to plot points in differnt lines to overlapping?

Tags: r

I want to plot several lists of points, each list has distance (decimal) and error_no (1-8). So far I am using the following:

```
plot(b1$dist1, b1$e1, col="blue",type="p", pch=20, cex=.5)
points(b1$dist2, b1$e2, col="blue", pch=22)
```

to add them both to the same plot. (I will add legends, etc later on).

The problem I have is that points overlap, and even when changing the character using for plotting, it covers up previous points. Since I am planning on plotting a lot more than just 2 this will be a big problem.

I found some ways in:

http://www.rensenieuwenhuis.nl/r-sessions-13-overlapping-data-points/

But I would rather do something that would space the points along the y axis, one way would be to add .1, then .2, and so on, but I was wondering if there was any package to do that for me.

Cheers
M
ps: if I missed something, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the very first point in the link you posted, `jitter` will slightly move all your points. If you just want to move the points on the y-axis:

```
plot(b1$dist1, b1$e1, col="blue",type="p", pch=20, cex=.5)
points(b1$dist2, jitter(b1$e2), col="blue", pch=22)
```

Comment: While that would be one way of doing it, I would prefer something that keeps things more ordered. Jitter, as far as I now, just adds noise to the value.

I found the function space() from the package gplots that seems to do this, but it does not seem to pick up two things. First is doesn't seem to respect the displacement between the call to plot and points, subsequents work. And it does not stretch the axis so points end up overlapping between the various values.

http://hosho.ees.hokudai.ac.jp/~kubo/Rdoc/library/gplots/html/space.html

Comment: If I understand you correctly, to keep things more "ordered" you would like to add an equal amount of jitter to each point. Then, if the new spacing caused another overlap, you would like to further move the point. It would be best if you gave example data, and then showed what you want the plot to look like.

Comment: As I replied below, got round using space() and characters that are easy to see if they superimpose. Probably ggplot2 should be the way forward.

Answer (score 2):

Depends a lot on what information you wish to impart to the reader of your chart.  A common solution is to use the transparency quality of R's color specification.  Instead of calling a color "blue" for example,  set the color to `#0000FF44`   (Apologies if I just set it to red or green)  The final two bytes define the transparency, from 00 to FF, so overlapping data points will appear darker than standalone points.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `spread.labs` function in the `TeachingDemos` package, particularly the example.  It may be that you can use that function to create your plot (the examples deal with labels, but could just as easily be applied to the points themselves).  The key is that you will need to find the new locations based on the combined data, then plot.  If the function as is does not do what you want, you could still look at the code and use the ideas to spread out your points.

Another approach would be to restructure your data and use the `ggplot2` package with "dodging".  Other approaches rather than using `points` several times would be the `matplot` function, using the `col` argument to plot with a vector, or `lattice` or `ggplot2` plots.  You will probably need to restructure the data for any of these.

Comment: I saw this and I think I will use ggplot2 for future plots. So far I managed to make it work using space() and using points that are easy to see if they superimpose. Squares and small dots.